# Texstudio shows undefinded sheme in "path:pattern"

Tags: texstudio, java

I try to configure TeXstudio (version 2.12.22) to work with LanguageTool v 4.8.
As I run the Help> Check LanguageTool configuration I get the message

```
Process started: where C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jre-11.0.6.10-hotspot\bin\java.exe

ERROR: invalid scheme in "path:pattern".

Process finished with Error(s)
```

*(roughly translated from German)*

If I start LanguageTool manually (GUI from command line) with activated server everything works perfectly.

Any ideas on that "path:pattern"-error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an interpretation issue of spaces in the paths which is fixed by the developer since 2020-02-21. Will be fixed for version TeXStudio version 3.0 and above.